# how do i print eachother while sentence?

Tags: python

i coded 6number from1 to 45 without duplicating

```
 from random import *
 lotto = []   
 while True:
    
    m = randrange(1, 46)
    if m not in lotto:
       lotto.append(m)
    
    if len(lotto) == 6:
            break
```

but I want to make different 6number as wanting

example, if i input 2 {1,21,23,43,35,26} {21,15,6,37,28,7}

but with this code,

```
for i in range(init(input""))
print(lotto)
```

same result is printed

i wanna different result

how do i add it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're after but as a note using

```
lotto.append(m.pop())
```

in place of

```
if m not in lotto:
   lotto.append(m)
```

Is faster and removes the poped character from m (preventing any logic errors in the future)

edit:
Apologies I haven't used the random module in a while and I thought `randrange` was generating a list not a number, therefore `pop` will not work and the original implementation is correct. However, for this purpose `random.sample` is a far better function to use

Comment: `m` (i.e. the return value of `randrange`) is an integer: calling `.pop()` on it will fail.

Comment: thx for ur reply , i didn't know 'pop'.
thx i'll use pop

Comment: `m.pop()` would not work here, because `m` is an integer.  `pop` is for types like sets and lists.

Comment: @slothrop  apologies I haven't used the random module in a little while and I assumed it was generating a list, tupple or some other kind of iterable I should have read the code more carefully

Answer (score 0):

you can put the lotto genrator in a function :

```
from random import randrange

def give_lotto():
  lotto = []

  while True:

      m = randrange(1, 46)
      if m not in lotto:
          lotto.append(m)

      if len(lotto) == 6:
          break
  
  return(lotto)
```

then print( result in the loop) in your example it gives you the same result because it doesn't generate it again it just prints the final result twie that's why putting it into a function will give your intended result

```
for i in range(int(input())):
  print(give_lotto())
```

Comment: thx sir,i learned while in function .
thx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are wanting to produce a list of `n` lotto combinations

```
import random


def n_lotto(n):
    lotto_draws = []
    for i in range(n):
        balls = random.sample(range(1, 46), 7)
        lotto_draws.append(balls)
    
    return lotto_draws
```

As a side note as you appear to be new a quick FYI. Python is a slow language butit has a lot of powerful builtin functions most of which are written in C and are therefore blazing fast, they are also extremely well tested meaning that it is almost always a good idea to have a quick google for a builtin if what you are trying to do is relatively simple as:

- it'll be easier to read
- it'll be faster
- you're less likely to have bugs